# How do I add classical categories in Unity's Dash?

Tags: unity, 11.04, unity-dash

I want to use the classical GNOME categories (Accessories, Education, Games, Office, Sound and Video) in the Dash menu instead of the current Media Apps | Internet Apps | More Apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try taking a look at the **Unity Bliss Lens**, which puts applications into category folders in the dash.

[image: Screenshot of Unity Bliss Lens]

**Instructions for installation:**

1. Download the package from https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-bliss by clicking the green button on the right side of the page.
2. Extract the package into your home folder.
3. Run the following in a terminal:

   ```
   cd unity-lens-bliss-0.1.3
   ./configure –prefix=/usr –sysconfdir=/etc
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Log out and back in to see it in the Dash.

([Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/unity-bliss-an-alternative-application-lens-for-ubuntu/))

Comment: This is identical to this other post from you http://askubuntu.com/questions/85815/classic-categories-in-unitys-dash/85816#85816. Cannot you link to that post, instead of reproduce the same content here?

Comment: @enzotib I moved the answer here after Jorge Castro asked me to. The idea is that the other question is a duplicate of this one, and the answers should go on the master question. I suppose I could delete the other post, but I'll ask about it in chat or on Meta first.

Comment: I've closed the other question and have deleted the answer. This is now the only copy.

Answer (score 6):

Old school dash

[image]

PPA - `ppa:shnatsel/unity` ([How to use PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351))

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't change the dash itself, but it does present you with a categorized view of installed applications. You can access it directly by using super+a, or you can just open the dash and tap tab to switch to it -- or click the App lens icon at the bottom of the dash. Anyway, it'll look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't go in the dash, but it adds a classic menu application indicator:

https://askubuntu.com/a/46811/18665