# How do I get a main menu in Unity?

Tags: unity, menu, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to add a main menu button to the unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42808/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-main-menu-button-to-the-unity-panel)

Hi there!
I installed the 11.04 beta2 and I have played with it, for some days.

I still miss though a kind of main menu (gnomenu, mainmemu, what ever).
Is there a way to put an icon of a mainmenu in the unity dash?

Thank you for your attention.
Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patched version of Unity where the dash has the contents of the old menus. See [How do I add classical categories in Unity's Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-add-classical-categories-in-unitys-dash)