# Is there a way to add a main menu button to the unity panel?

Tags: 11.04, unity, menu

I like many of the features of unity (ubuntu 11.04). I use a netbook and so enjoy having less wasted space. The side menu is fine too. However where is the main menu? Using the dash to get there is not easy as the icon is already off the bottom of the screen (I tried to move it to the top) and besides dash is slow, slow, slow. The main menu is one click and move the mouse to the application you have but are not sure of the name and click and go. Dash means a row of most used, then a row of others which needs a click to see the rest... then you click that and still have to search some more. I see something about "white listing" stuff for the unity panel. Is there some way to use this to add a main menu. I can live with and even enjoy everything else.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a main menu button on the dock called applications (dark grey lower half) if you right click you will get the typical main menu entries and then the dash format opens. I would be also happy if I could move this "icon" to the top in case I dont remember (happens I am over 50) the name of the app and want to use my graphical memory by switching to classic view (like in windows). Bottom line, the functionality is there, just lets hope a more knowledgeable person will enable us to move this function to the place where we want to see it.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your **question***, no. The Unity panel and the GNOME panel are two completely different and mostly unrelated pieces of software.

**please avoid rants.*

Answer (score 1):

maybe you will be satisfied with this: http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2011/05/get-best-of-both-worldsyour-own.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+UbuntuVibes+%28Ubuntu+Vibes%29

Comment: Sorry I didnt checked the link before posting my answer. The link provides me with a nearly perfect solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**ClassicMenu Indicator**

ClassicMenu Indicator is a notification area applet (application indicator) for the top panel of Ubuntu’s Unity desktop environment. It provides a simple way to get a classic GNOME-style application menu for those who prefer this over the Unity dash menu. Like the classic GNOME menu, it includes Wine games and applications if you have those installed. 
[image]

*installattion*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```