# classic categories in Unity's dash?

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add classical categories in Unity's Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-add-classical-categories-in-unitys-dash)

I have installed ubuntu 11.10
I would like to get the classic menu categories on the dash home
Is there a possibility to customize the home dash as I like it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/34670/18612